# Child Div is not removed when tried to remove using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Clearing child div inside parent div, there are many answers like :

```
 $(".ChildDiv").html("");
 $('.ChildDiv > div').remove();
 $(".ChildDiv").html("");
 $("#ParentDiv").html("");
 $(".ChildDiv div").remove();
 $(".ChildDiv div").empty();
 $('.ChildDiv ').find('div').remove();
```

Probably I have listed all possible way to remove the div's, but even after using all these, I still not able to clear all the div's inside Parent Div. let me explain what I am doing and what I need.

Scenario :

I have two container-1, one of the container has input search box, where I can search for entering employee name and select few employees Ex. 5 and can use "Add" button to move those employees to the other container-2 which is 'div'.

[image]

Now I click on report button event and get the information of those 5 people in different aspx, now if i go back to the page where i have to search for another 3 employees and when I again click on the "Add" button, it should add only 3 employees instead it is adding last searched 5 + 3 employees!!.

[image]

[image]

So i am trying to clear the 5 employees inside that div after i click on "Report" button , when i use alert() it says it has 0 element, but when I add it for the second time, it appends the data again, which i dont need. here is the code :

Points to remember :
1. ParentDiv is the container-2
2. ChildDiv is the child div inside ParentDiv(which is dynamically appended when we select 5 employees on "Add" button click"

Here is the code:

**HTML** :

```
 <table id="topTable">
    <tr>
        <td id="leftpane">
             <h4>Search for Employee by Name or Profile:</h4>
             <input type="text" id="EmployeeSearchBox" class="search-box" aria-multiselectable="true" />
             <select id="EmployeeList" size="20" multiple></select>
        </td>
        <td id="centerpane">
            <div> <input type="button" value="Add >>" class="AddButton" id="buttonAdd" /></div>                
            <div> <input type="button" value="Add All >>" class="AddButton" id="buttonAddAll" /></div>

        </td>
        <td id="rightpane">
             <h4>Selected Employees:</h4>
    <div id="ParentDiv"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Run Report button event**

```
 <input class="data" type="submit" name="cmdSubmit" value="Run Report" onclick="return FormValidate();"
                    onserverclick="RunReport" runat="server" id="Submit1" />
```

**Add Button Click :**
which moves the employees from container-1 to container-2.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#buttonAdd', function (e) {       

    $('#EmployeeList :selected').each(function (i, selected) {           
        myHash[$(selected).val()] = $(selected).text();
    });

    var myNode = $("#ParentDiv")[0];

    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }
    for (var emp_id in myHash) {
     var emp =   $("#ParentDiv").append("<div class= ChildDiv id=" + emp_id + ">" + myHash[emp_id] + " <span class='close'>&times;</Span> </div>");            
    }  
    $('#EmployeeSearchBox').val("").trigger('input');  
});
```

On click of "Report" button it should clear all the elements from ParentDiv/ChildDiv which is what I did, but still it is not clearing it, how can I resolve/remove these elements once "Report" button event clicked.

Here is a sample of "**Report**" button event :

```
function FormValidate() {//Part of my other code
$(".ChildDiv").html("");
$('.ChildDiv > div').remove();
$(".ChildDiv").html("");
$("#ParentDiv").html("");
$(".ChildDiv div").remove();
$(".ChildDiv div").empty();
$('.ChildDiv ').find('div').remove();
  }
```

None of them is working, i feel there is an issue with the "Add" button event, where it is storing the data.

**NOTE :**

I don't want to clear the array of employee list, since I want to select multiple employees again again Ex. I can select 2 employees starts with the letter "M" and I can search the 2 employees of letter "L" and add those 2 employees, the container should hold 4 employees before "Report" button click.

Let me know if I am clear enough.

**Console Log**

[image]

Comment: please share your html code to debug easily

Comment: Apparently there is much code in HTML, but I have shared it now, its just a basic <div>

Comment: Where are you calling the `FormValidate()` function?

Comment: Can you `alert("test");` within your `FormValidate()` function, to see if it's even called properly? Let us know!

Comment: Yes, Sina. if it is not calling then I couldn't generate report right ? so I could able to see the report after that FormValidate() which does all my validation part.

Comment: Alright great. Then I suggest you to look into `console.log($(".ChildDiv"));` and see what it returns.

Comment: Like what you want to know ?, were the items are cleared ? if so yes it is getting cleared, when I use :  var count1 = $('.selectedItemss').children('div').remove();
            var count = count1.length;
            alert("count " + count);, The count returns "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I could able to fix the issue**, i was facing, I am posting the answer, now it is working as I need.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#buttonAdd', function (e) {

    var div_count = $('#ParentDiv').find('div').length;
    if (div_count === 0) {
        myHash = []; // Clearing the hash, so that it can add fresh employees, if count == 0 in container- 2.
        $('#EmployeeList :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
            myHash[$(selected).val()] = $(selected).text();
        });
    }
    else { // If there are existing employees in container-2 then append few more. 
        $('#EmployeeList :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
            myHash[$(selected).val()] = $(selected).text();
        });
    }

    var myNode = $("#ParentDiv")[0];
    console.log(myNode);

    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }
    for (var emp_id in myHash) {
        var emp = $("#ParentDiv").append("<div class= ChildDiv id=" + emp_id + ">" + myHash[emp_id] + " <span class='close'>&times;</Span> </div>");
        }
    $('#EmployeeSearchBox').val("").trigger('input');
});
```

**What I did**

Since I should be able to append multiple employees by searching, that is handled in 'else' part, if I generated the "Report" then, I am clearing the Container-2.

When I come back to page to search few more employees, by this time Container-2 will not be having any employees, so

```
var div_count = $('#ParentDiv').find('div').length;
if (div_count === 0) {
 myHash = [];
 //....
 }
```

will clear the array which allow me to add fresh employees, hence it solved my problem :)

Thanks all for the support.

Comment: Why do you answer your own question if I already gave you the answer? And not even a thank you for all the hours I invested...

Comment: Clearing 'myHash' in FormValidate() will not help me, I have to check the container div's, based on that I have to append the employees, if not Have to clear those. The code you suggested will clear the entire array(before generating report), but I need to handle both the scenarios.

Comment: Well you could have said so. Your question was never clear enough to give you a proper answer. We always had to guess what code would be executed when. But I definitly pointed to the correct solution by pointing to resetting myHash.

Comment: I apologies if my english is bad in this case, to make it clear I used to post images too, so that I was clear what am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to adjust on comments:

You need to clear the myHash variable. Otherwise employees will be added again from there.

Comment: I can't use the above code, it clears the data before running the report. I should be able to add many employees based on search selection and this will not allow to do that, whenever I try to add more employees it clears the existing data in that container and adds new.

Comment: Or is there a way to retain the employee list and add new employees into the container ? this scenario is before running the report.

Comment: Then you need to clear the list in the right place. Maybe FormValidate()?